# Lightweight ES6 transpilation

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

Comming from a java background, I am surprised to see how much setup is required, in order to transpile an es6/reactjs/jsx application to es5.

I got a long way by installing node/npm/babel, performing on-the-fly transpilation with 'babel --watch $srcdir --out-dir $targetdir'.

But once I add an import or require statement to my script file, I need the transpiler to add polyfills, and every example I have seen so far requires a vast amount of dependencies to be installed manually with npm (which may or may not work when installed globally), declaration of the same dependencies in a package file, and yet another decalaration of them in a grunt/grub/webpack/something build file, which also needs to have various tasks defined.

I admit to be totally inexperienced with the various js tool chains, is there a simple way of doing this, which doesn't require all of this tedious setup?

Comment: You'll find a ton of people that absolutely *love* babel  is so far off from many other tools that are so incredibly bad... I honestly have no friction with it and you'll be hard-pressed to find anything close in terms of power, utility, and ease-of-use.

Comment: It sounds like the problem here is a lack of willingness to learn the environment. ES6 transpilation is not easy, therefore understanding it is not easy. You should read up on what Node *is* instead of seeing it as a dependency of Babel. Read about what Grunt & Gulp *do* instead of assuming they're required. Same with webpack/browserify. Understanding that will allow you to narrow down your toolchain considerably

Comment: I'm little confused about you statement that babel requires "vast amount of dependencies". In node.js babel works out of the box, and in a browser you only need a single polyfill script that comes with `babel`. And if you're using `webpack`, you could automatically include all polyfills into you build with a single flag.

Comment: Just to repeat the question: "Is there a simple way of doing ES6 transpilation, which doesn't require a lot of tedious setup?"

Comment: @BrianPedersen Yes. Using babel. `babel srcdir --out-file es5.js` will compile all files in srcdir into a single javascript file. No module loader or task runner required. Add the polyfill if you need it.

Comment: And if you're coming from a Java background, take a look at IntelliJ or WebStorm - they both have Babel integration baked in

Comment: from what i underdstand the OP asks for a library (e.g a single file utility or script) which does the es5 transpilation, insteda of loading a whole environment which may provide more features but also needs more configuration and details etc.. As fasr as unwillingness to learn environments is concerned, i would say it bypasses the issue. The issue is not to load and learn a ton of details about an enviroment which is not critical to the task, just to do a simple thing, else just use C or assmbly and everything else is an extra dependency, my .2 cents

Comment: for what is worth there is a [micro-es5-loader-polyfill](https://github.com/caridy/es6-micro-loader) which polyfills the `System.import` both in browser and node (just 2 files), but requires transpiling if native es5 modules are to be used (i.e with declarative `import`)